# How to read value of parameter defined in text file

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell

I am using the below command to read the value of parameter defined in txt file.

```
$asid = Get-Content -Path config.cfg | Select-String -Pattern 'NW_GetSid' | ForEach-Object { $_.line.split('= ') }
```

The parameter is defined as below in file:

```
Hostname = hostname
NW_GetSid = ABC
```

The command gives the output with blank line first & then outputs:

```
Blank line
ABC
```

How can I avoid the blank line in my result as in output I just need `ABC` to get stored in asid variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a regex to retrieve the value of your desired property

[image]

```
$asid = [regex]::Match((get-content config.cfg -Raw), 'NW_GetSid\s*=\s*(\w+)').Groups[1].Value
```